# Improve number recognition with Python-Tesseract (OCR)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ocr, python-tesseract

I'm working in Python with Pillow and Tesseract to recognize the numbers from an output log image with a single line of text containing 3 columns of numbers (number, date & decimal number - link below).

https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/ISyZzRXHaceRL_TSw1_hrEKdrP3EDF7gmRjaMxwqMXfIE-APBusNvApAP7kFsFNEQHM=w2400

*Pytesseract Output:*

*73606, 2622-66-22 16:26:64:499 6.86233648*

The output is quite good but **it keeps returning the zeros (0) as six (6) or even eights (8)**. How can I improve the zeros recognition?

I've tried sharpenning the image, different scaling, extending the timeout and different psm config but the result is the same or worse. I've also tried pre-processing with cv2 but the result is not better than this one.

```
#Using Pillow to open and pre-process image
img = img_path #Set image path
img = PIL.Image.open(img).convert("L") #Convert to gray-scale
img = ImageOps.invert(img) #Invert
size_factor = 5 #Size factor to resize image
img = img.resize((img.size[0] * size_factor, img.size[1] * size_factor)) #Resize image

#Pytesseract to recognize numbers
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = Path(r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe')
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(img,
                                   lang='eng',
                                   timeout=30,
                                 config="--psm 7")
print(txt)

Output:
73606, 2622-66-22 16:26:64:499 6.86233648
```